# What are the problems with templates on Windows? What are the solutions?

Tags: c++, windows, templates, dll

I'm on Linux, and trying to write cross-platform code. I know that templates are difficult to use properly on Windows, but I don't remember the specifics.

I do know that one problem has to do with template debugging and templates that cross dll boundaries, but not how to work around it - or if a workaround is even possible.

I believe that there are other issues, but I've only found vague references to them.

So: What are the problems with C++ templates on Windows? Aside from not using templates, what are the solutions?

---

**Edit:** Maybe the problems are only with the `STL`, and not with templates in general?

Two quotes:

> You cannot expose STL calls across library boundaries on windows without significant headaches.

and

> Encapsulation is a must, I have done some projects with stl containers over dll boundaries as well as static libraries on windows and it's not possible to use without encapsulation.

Comment: It depends on compile, not OS...

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. There's no windows specific problem with templates. Dlls should be ok as well, as long as you don't mix CRTs, compilers, and don't use statically linked crts with dlls. Instead of reading dubious info from untrusted sources (**who** said "encapsulation is a must"? Is this guy even experienced?), why don't you simply try to use dlls with templates and see what happens? If you run into problem, you can always ask *specific* question.

Comment: @SigTerm the guy who said that has many years of experience as a developer on windows.  I could install windows on a vm and try it myself, but in the past I've struggled to do builds on windows.

Comment: @Mark: "has many years of experience as a developer on windows" I'm not convinced. Many years of experience does not guarantee skill or deep knowledge of C++ - the guy could've stuck with C-style coding using pure winapi, without ever acquiring understanding of templates or STL, for example. Try building the project yourself, ask question when you run into problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that templates are difficult to use properly on Windows.

I've never heard such a thing. Sounds like baseless [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt), which I suggest you completely ignore.

Comment: I've updated the question. Maybe the problems are only with `STL`?

Comment: @Mark: Presumably you mean the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: I speak of only part of it - the templates. `STL` is an imperfect label, but people do generally know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one problem, [from the MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;168958) (**edit:** this one only pertains to MSVC 5 and 6; I have no intentions of supporting such an ancient compiler, so it's irrelevant to me):

> Some STL classes contain nested classes. These classes can not be exported. For instance, deque contains a nested class deque::iterator. If you export deque, you will get a warning that you must export deque::iterator. If you export deque::iterator, you get a warning that you must export deque. This is caused by a designed limitation that once a template class is instantiated, it can not be re-instantiated and exported. The only STL container that can currently be exported is vector. The other containers (that is, map, set, queue, list, deque) all contain nested classes and cannot be exported.

Comment: IIRC, VC11's stdlib adopted SCARY iterators, which frees the iterators from the parent container's allocator, comparator, hasher, etc. This can't be implemented with nested classes, only with free ones + a typedef. Maybe it's not an issue anymore?

Comment: @Xeo I just looked at that page again, and it only pertains to MSVC 5 and 6.